# Building a routing API

Tags: ruby, api, rest, soa

I need to build a API that basically exposes certain URI endpoints and maps them to any number of backend URL's.

So the API would have mappings in Mongo like this:

```
{"name": "example", "from": "/resources", "to": "http://backendservice.com/1/billing", "method": "POST"}

{"name": "example1", "from": "/resources/:id", "to": "http://backendservice.com/1/billing/:id", "method": "GET"}

{"name": "example2", "from": "/somethingelse/*", "to": "http://google.com/foo/*", "method": "ANY"}
```

The purpose here is to have a single entry point all our clients can use to access all the various services. It also allows simplified logging and reporting.

So if we request api.example.org/resources the system matches the incoming request URL to a destination URL. Makes the request to destination and receives the response, does appropriate logging and deals with any errors. Makes sense?

My question(s):

Are there any out of the box open source solutions that does this?

Which frameworks/libs etc would you suggest as a good starting point. I've looked at Goliath (Ruby) but am not limited to any language as long as it's open source and linux.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I've decided to go with API Umbrella.

https://github.com/NREL/api-umbrella

It provides exactly what I need. Built with Ruby, uses mongo, does routing. Perfect.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to go beyond Ruby, you can use the Python library [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/). Also, you can do this with Ruby's built-in WEBrick HTTP server library. Just create a servlet that does a lookup in the URL dictionary, or create many servlets dynamically with metaprogramming, and mount them on your different URLS.

Comment: WEBrick is slow and cant deal with concurrent requests if I remember correctly?

Comment: Flask looks cool but how is it any different than using for example Sinatra?

Comment: @Johandk: I think it can now, but let me check.

Comment: @Johandk: Not very. I've just never used Sinatra. Anyway, Flask doesn't assume that you're trying to write a webapp, which I've found helpful.

Answer (score 0):

WSO2API Manager is a fully opensource product , which is available under apcheV2 license.

Where you can  achive this multiple endpoint configuration with APIManager and ESB.
When you publish a API, you might need to point one service endpoint(it can be a proxy endpoint/another REST API at wso2esb) and from the ESB end you can route the requests to multiple endpoints based on the request.

Comment: Checking this out now. Looks promising.